# Ext JS 3.2.1 Grid using Ext.fly to highlight a cell after that the original cell line and color not restore?

Tags: extjs, grid

I use below code to highlight a cell in an ExtJS grid

```
Ext.fly(TargetCell, "ID").highlight("CCFF33", {
                                            attr: "background-color",
                                            duration: 5
                                    });
```

It works well except that after highlight the cell will not return to original color and even the cell line were gone. Illustrated in below images, notice the second row Pending changed to Sold then the row line and background color became white

http://img231.imageshack.us/img231/2601/beforeextfly.jpg

http://img847.imageshack.us/img847/857/afterextfly.jpg

Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css class. A quick rough example would be...

```
myGrid.on('rowclick', function (grid, rowindex) {

    var view = grid.getView();
    if (view.getRow(this.currentIndex)) {
        Ext.fly(view.getRow(this.currentIndex)).removeClass('highlight');
    }

    Ext.fly(view.getRow(rowindex)).addClass('highlight');

    this.currentIndex = rowindex;

}, this);
```

Comment: Hi Dve, how do i get the original class of the row that i just highlighted? So that i can restore back that class after highlight.

Comment: Instead of worry about doing that why not just add a class that overwrites the properties of your original class. then when you remove it the style will just fall back to the standard.